# Ajax database to request with a dropdown list

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu

Dropdown list to request from another php but using 2 dropdown list to search for it.

If selected age (41) then user clicks on lastname dropdown box, the user will only be able to select either Peter Griffin and Glen Quagmire on the lastname dropdown box. AND Peter Griffin and Glen Quagmire data will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want the content of the select boxes to change dynamically based on the users selection of the opposite box.

My way of doing this would be with to bind jQuery $().change() event handlers to each select box. When the user changes the select box the event will fire, and your code should then perform a AJAX GET request, again using jQuery ($.get()) to your back-end, probably a PHP script, which does the filtering and returns as JSON the options for the second dropdown.

EDIT: Example below. The $.get calls to a back-end php script which returns JSON used to fill the other select box.

```
<select id="lastname"><option value="Will">Will</option><option value="John">John</option></select>
<select id="age"><option value="45">45</option><option value="41">41</option></select>

$("#lastname").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $.get('backend.php?n=' + value, function(data) {
           $("#age").empty();
           $.each(data, function() {
               $("#age").append("<option value='" + this.value+ "'>" + this.content + "</option");
           });
      }, "json");
});

$("#age").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $.get('backend.php?a=' + value, function(data) {
           $("#lastname").empty();
           $.each(data, function() {
               $("#lastname").append("<option value='" + this.value+ "'>" + this.content + "</option");
           });
      }, "json");
});
```